# Is the system $\left\{\frac{e^{i n t}}{2\pi}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ a Riesz basis on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the system
$$\left\{\frac{e^{i n t}}{2\pi}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$$
a Riesz basis on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$? I think not because
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{i (n-m) t}}{4\pi^2}dt\neq 1$$
if $n=m$. Right?

Comment: As written, it would seem you're right.  Perhaps it was a typo, and they meant $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ on the bottom.

Comment: You're confusing a Reisz basis with an orthonormal basis I think, what you've written is the conditional for the latter. You should check the Riesz condition.

Comment: Sorry but definition is: "A basis $\{x_n\}$ for a Hilbert space H is a Riesz basis for H if it is equivalent to some (and therefore every) orthonormal basis for H". This means that also $\{x_n\}$ is a orthonormal basis.Or am I wrong?